# Do these sentences need "the": "driving in deserts", "camp for night"

Tags: articles

Should it be "in the deserts"?

> "Jake was behind the wheel, as driving **in deserts** was his specialty."

Should I say "for the night"?

> "They were going to camp around the national park with their team **for night**"

Comment: An interesting question, but we usually ask about one issue at a time. So it would've looked even better as two interesting questions. (0:

Comment: Where are you getting these sentences from? Are you writing a short story? You've asked about a half-dozen questions in a matter of hours, and all of them seem scant on details. It might be time to read [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) (both that meta question, and some of the answers below it. Strive to write questions that will be of value to other English learners, not just to you, by (a) giving more context, and (b) explaining more about why you are in doubt.

Comment: Thank you. I read the link you provided and I'll be more careful about asking questions.

Answer (score 4):

driving in the desert -  not in a city, not in a savanna, not in a forest, **but** in a particular desert, the desert as a terrain, the particular desert as a location. (will depend on the context, I think in the OP's context, it is the desert as a terrain)

for the night - not tomorrow night, not another night, **but** the night according to the context (in the OP's context, the night during the camp).

Answer (score 2):

It would typically be driving "in the desert" (you could also say "desert driving").

And yes, for "the" night. More commonly "in" or "near" the park for a single night.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "driving in deserts" or "driving in the desert" because you are not referring to a specific desert; you mean any desert.

As you are referring to a specific night, you should say "for the night". You can also say "for a night" if you want to say one night.